# Run multiple instance of a process on a number of servers

Tags: distributed-computing

I would like to run multiple instances of a randomized algorithm. For performance reason, I'd like to distribute the tasks on several machines.

Typically, I run my program as follows:

```
./main < input.txt > output.txt
```

and it takes about 30 minutes to return a solution.

I would like to run as many instances of this as possible, and ideally not change the code of the program. My questions are:

1 - What online services offer computing resources that would suit my need?

2 - Practically, how should I launch remotely all the processes, get notified of the termination, and then aggregate the results (basically, pick up the best solution). Is there a simple framework that I could use or should I look into ssh-based scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - What online services offer computing resources that would suit my need?

Amazon EC2.

> 2 - Practically, how should I launch remotely all the processes, get notified of the termination, and then aggregate the results (basically, pick up the best solution). Is there a simple framework that I could use or should I look into ssh-based scripting?

Amazon EC2 has an API for launching virtual machines. Once they're launched, you can indeed use ssh to control jobs, and I would recommend this solution. I would expect that other softwares for distributed job management exist, but they aren't likely to be any simpler to configure than ssh.